# Cleaned my solution and deleted my windows service exe

Tags: c#, service

I just cleaned my solution and realized it also cleaned my windows service. My problem is that it deleted the exe file of my service.

Is there any possibility to get this file back? Recreating the file or generating a new one?

Ask if you miss information or have questions.

Comment: How was the "windows service" built in the first place?

Comment: in visual studio. later added an installer, installed it then cleaned the solution and now my exe is gone

Comment: I replaced it with a regenerated exe from earlier but when I build the solution now it also gets deleted!?

Comment: you have the service and installer both in the same sln? build the projects one at a time to watch which one creates the service and which one deletes it